# AuthComponent not available in certain controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have written my cake app to log in registered users and it works great on view pages where there is a db model associated with a User.  However, on my main pages that aren't necessarily accessing some model (the PagesController where pages are things like upcoming events, contact us, about, etc), AuthComponent is not available, or at the least, the array returns empty---so i cannot retrieve, say, the username of the person logged in.

I tried creating a model called Page that belongsTo User but that didn't fix my problem.

To explain a little further, my app shows lists of certain lodgings, nightclubs, restaurants and things to do for a given city, all of which is shown whether a user is logged in or not.  I don't understand where I am going wrong and why.

Here is my AppController:

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);


function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login', 'logout','index', 'view', 'condos', 'houses', 'hotels_and_motels', 'print_all_coupons', 'print_coupon', 'search', 'golf', 'charters', 'events', 'nightlife', 'shopping', 'visitors_info', 'contact_us');

}
}
?>
```

here is where I access my username in my default page layout:

```
<?php if(AuthComponent::user('id')) {
        echo '<span style="font-variant:small-caps">Hello, '.AuthComponent::user('username').'</span> | ';
?>
```

Comment: You may need to provide more code to help us get a picture of what the code base is doing.

Comment: Using Components in views is a bad practice, undermines separation of layers in MVC. I'd $this->set("userId") in beforeRender for example to be user as $userId in all views. It is also good for performance as you access the session only once and re-use the value in a variable.

Comment: Thank you, that was something i was unaware of (am very new at this!).   But don't you think this is moot since the user id isn't available on these pages (for whatever reason we cannot figure out) to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer, after weeks of beating my head on the wall about this.  And oh, you're gonna laugh.  For any of you out there up against this problem, the answer is.....make sure there is no white space before or after your  tags.  That is all.  Seriously.  Since PHP prints out everything that isn't in a PHP tag, if it finds something to send, it will send out headers before everything else.  Once headers are sent, a PHP session cannot be created.  So chalk this one up to the head-smacking file!

Comment: Dear god, thank you for this. This morning a controller I'd been using for weeks suddenly had to Auth session key, and I was about thirty seconds from calling either a priest or the ghost busters to fix it. mah hero.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  No white space in your View?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code my first instinct is to say that you are not loading the component in AppController but in the UsersController only. Are you loading the Auth component in AppController?

**UPDATE:**

Here is how I would suggest accessing the User information.

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.username');
```

**UPDATE 2**

Remove the `$components` declaration from the Pages Controller. It could be overriding the session.

**UPDATE 3**

If you have a custom Pages controller, it is probably conflicting with the Core Pages controller. Remove your Pages controller and see if it works correctly. The Core Pages controller will still route to the `Views/Pages/` directory for displaying content.

Comment: I thought I added it correctly.  Please see the OP, as I have shown my AppController code.

Comment: How are you accessing the name of the User for use within the app?

Comment: I tried adding this into the index() method for the PagesController, and it didn't work on the index page (one of the spots it wasn't working before).  I even tried sticking it in place of AuthComponent::user('username') in the page layout.

Comment: Print the debug of the session data to the screen `pr($this->Session->read('Auth.User');` so you can see what is stored in the session.

Comment: The debug prints on all pages NOT in PagesController, the others, it prints nothing. It sees no session, I think, in this controller, and I have public $components = array('Auth', 'Acl', 'Session'); in the class declaration of PagesController.

Comment: Take the $components declaration out of the pages controller. The AppController will be used. That could be resetting the Session.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was something I added on, thinking it might solve things.  Even so, I tried it, and no go.

Comment: Hmm, the plot is thickening.  I added <?php pr($_SESSION); ?> to my page layout, and on some of these PagesController pages, I get an "undefined variable _SESSION" error, and on some pages, I get an empty array!

Comment: Are you using the Core Pages controller? Or do you actually have a table in the database called pages and your own controller called Pages?

Comment: No, I have a PagesController with no table in the database, and no Page model.  I used it for pages where I a)had no model that I needed to retrieve info from, or 2)any page that only had only one page/one model.  Some of my pages have their own controllers because they have multiples 'types';  i.e.  the Lodgings controller has pages for condos, houses, and hotels, the Restaurants controller has pages for italian, steakhouse, fine dining, etc.

Comment: That may be the problem. The core comes with a pages controller already. Try changing the name to Documents. Or if you have a Pages view already set up, just remove the pages controller and let the core route those for you.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, created a DocsController, moved all my pages for it into a view folder called Docs, rerouted those pages, and still no session information.  I will say that I get an empty array on docs pages where a model call is made, and a "undefined variable _SESSION" on index, contact us docs pages.  I can easily create controllers for the pages with model calls on them but that still leaves me in the cold for my generic pages.

Comment: I do not experience that at all. What version of Cake are you using? 2.0.6? Was this code you migrated or new code? Have you tried running a fresh dev install and testing it there?

Comment: I believe I am using 2.0.4.  This is all new code.  No dev install, never done that, have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You should upgrade to stable. A dev install is just another plain install with the plain app directory and none of your code in it.

Comment: I was sure I had a stable release (I got it in November I want to say), but I am not sure I follow how to do a dev install.  Can you recommend a tutorial that will help me to do this?

Comment: Just do a fresh install in a different location and use it to test with. As for your existing 2.0.4 version, just drop in the newest stable release for the core.

Comment: Ok, I am SERIOUSLY a noob.  When you say "for the core", what do you mean?  Drop in all the folders except the app folder?

Comment: Yes. The new CakePHP core files.